# Grid view Frame layout in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-framelayout, onitemclicklistener

Hi In my application I have designed it by using GridView with frame layout, in that I am displaying image with text.That items I added in items now my problem is how to write the on click button for different items.

For Example: If I click the about us, I want to open some activity.if I click photo gallery, I want to open another activity.
    can anyone please tell me how to write that one.

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            items.add(new Item("About Us", R.drawable.aboutus));
            items.add(new Item("Photo Gallery", R.drawable.photo));
            items.add(new Item("Veg Food", R.drawable.veg));
            items.add(new Item("Non Veg Food", R.drawable.nonveg));
            items.add(new Item("Location", R.drawable.contactus));
            items.add(new Item("Contact Us", R.drawable.contactus));

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if(v == null)
            {
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
               v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
               v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);

            return v;
        }

        private class Item
        {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout


            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight="1" >
        <com.agilerise.hotel.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

             android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            />
        </FrameLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/buttom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:numColumns="3" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

if i use like this it's moving to same activity

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            //Grab the item position here and write further code
             switch (pos) {
             case 0:
                 Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Aboutus.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen);
                 break;
             case 1:
                 Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FlickrActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextScreen1);
                 break;


        }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code inside your `MainActivity`

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                //Grab the item position here and write further code
            }
        });
```

For your `Gridview` adapter set `ViewHolder` class like:

```
public class ViewHolder {

         ImageView picture;
         TextView name;
    }
```

And in `getView()`:-

```
View gridView = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            holder.name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

             gridView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
               holder = (ViewHolder) gridView.getTag();
            }
```

Remember using set and get Tag properly like above.

Comment: xml file it's changing from device to device why can you please tell me i want that one in the middle